# Problem in keeping the userlogged in after the page refreshes using localstorage and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I am trying to keep the user *logged in* after he/she refresh their page.
I set a variable `isLogged` with no value;
on signup this variable is assigns to the new user as `false` in their `localstorage` object `{isLogged: true }`

on *signin* this variable is assigned a value of `true`;
on *signout* this variable is assigned a value of `false`

I am trying to test on page load via  `codeAddress` to loop in the `localstorage`, since no user will have the `true` value instead of the last user that was logged in

I edited my code, it was a typo, this function is still not working

Not sure why my code isn't working

```
function codeAddress()  {        
  $.each(localStorage, function(iSlogged){
    if (iSlogged== true){
      menuChannelIcon.show();
          bellIcon.show();
          uploadButtonIcon.show();
          signInMainPageIcon.hide();
          signUpMainPageIcon.hide();
          signOutMainPageIcon.show();
          singIn_formContainer.hide();
          videoSectionMainPage.show();
          console.log("You were already LOGGED");
        }
     })
  }
```

Comment: You should post the code that shows where you're writing to localStorage as well.

Answer (score 0):

`iSlogged` is the param but `isLogged` is the var you're checking against.

Comment: yes but when the object is created in the sign up its is set as 
 {eml: email, pwd : password ,iSlogged : islogged} 

so example on account creation: 
Adamsmith@hotmail.com  
123456 
false 
on sign in: jquery changes stat to true 

Then the user decides to refresh page, so the value is still set to true     

Then the code in the question is executed onpage load

Comment: I edited my code, it was a typo, this function now doesnt allow me to even click my sign in button unless i comment it

Comment: you fixed a typo now your code doesn't work?

Comment: fixed it just now, however the function is still not working ;)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work with the following code, its not perfect cus for somereason it shows windows/buttons that are in the begining of the f condition so i have to repeat the hide function on the same element to make it work

```
function codeAddress()  {        
  for (const key in localStorage) {

    if (localStorage.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      if(key.val ==true)
      
               
               signUpMainPageIcon.hide();
               signUpMainPageIcon.hide();
               singIn_formContainer.hide();
               signOutMainPageIcon.show();
               videoSectionMainPage.show();
               signInMainPageIcon.hide();
               bellIcon.show();
               uploadButtonIcon.show();
               console.log("You were already LOGGED");
    }
}
}

window.onload = codeAddress;
```